# Is it possible to rent a kayak at Paros without guide?

Tags: greece, islands, canoeing-and-kayaking, cyclades-islands

I try to find out the websites that offer kayak renting at Paros (Greek island). However it seems to me that all the companies offer only guided tours on kayaks and me and my friend would prefer to do sea-kayaking on our own.

Is it possible? Is it the common practice for a Greek islands that one can only do sea-kayaking on a guided tours?

Bonus question: what is the best Greek Island to explore on kayaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen tourists kayaking without guides. I don't think it's a common practice that guides should be obligatory. I think you can work things out with a company and rent some kayaks without guides.

Honestly speaking, all the islands are great for exploring.
I've seen that you can rent a kayak in Zakynthos that is really exciting and has some great spots to explore with kayak. I would also recommend Milos island and Santorini (not sure if there are any kayak renting companies in Santorini though)

Comment: You can always e-mail or phone the renting company and ask!